# What is wrong with printing and assigning the input to a variable? Why is the variable value None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I don't know what I did wrong in this code:

```
name1 = print (input ("please enter name1: "))
name2 = print (input ("please enter name2: "))
combined_names = name1 + name2 
lower_names = combined_names.lower() 
t = lower_names.count("t")
r = lower_names.count("r")
u = lower_names.count("u")
e = lower_names.count("e")
first_digit = t + r + u + e

l = lower_names.count("l")
o = lower_names.count("o")
v = lower_names.count("v")
e = lower_names.count("e")
second_digit = l + o + v + e

score = int (str(first_digit) + str(second_digit))
if (score < 10) or (score > 90):
  print (f"your score is {score}, you go to gether like coke and mentos.")
elif (score >= 40) and (score<= 50):
  print (f"your score is {score}, you are alright together.")
else:
  print (f"your score is {score}.")
```

I keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    combined_names = name1 + name2 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
 
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I tried changing the variable `combined_names` but no luck.

Comment: Remove the calls to the `print` in the first two lines. `print` doesn't return anything. Instead of trying to add the two strings user entered, you are trying to add two of nothing so it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function automatically provides a prompt using the provided text. Surrounding the `input()` with the `print()` returns no value, which is causing the error.

To resolve the issue, simply remove `print()` when initializing the variables `name1` and `name2`.

Comment: "*...returns no value*": The more correct statement is that it returns the `None` value, and that `None` gets assigned to the variables `name1` and `name2`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I appreciate the clarification.